# Is there an easy way to have backgroundrb started with server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, backgroundrb

Is there an easy way to have backgroundrb started (restarted) when the server reboots?

Ex. What if your hosting use mongrel cluster and you have no access to it (except start/stop)
One of solution i found on forums is code snippet in backgroundrb plugin with check for PID exist (if not exist start with exec or system) etc. 
Just your ideas.

Comment: You should ask this on http://serverfault.com/ -- it'll depend on the server type you run

Answer (score 0):

My solution:
 in script/server before rails run add system call for bacgroundrb

```
# AUTO START BACKGROUDRB
#stop if already runing
system( "./script/backgroundrb stop")
#start
system( "./script/backgroundrb start")
```